# Not able to access Jenkins from browser seeing "400 Bad Request The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port". Using Istio-ingress gateway

Tags: jenkins, istio, istio-gateway

Jenkins installed through helm chart with a custom installation path.

```
helm install argo-jenkins -f jenkins-volume.yaml jenkinsci/jenkins -n jenkins --set controller.jenkinsUriPrefix='/jenkinsargo'
```

We have a front-end Istio-ingress gateway from all the browser requests.
GW.Yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: jenkins-gw
  namespace: jenkins
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
```

VS.Yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: jenkins-vs
  namespace: jenkins
spec:
  gateways:
  - jenkins-gw.jenkins
  hosts:
  - '*'
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /jenkinsargo
    route:
    - destination:
        host: argojenkins.jenkins.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 8080
```

Able to access jenkins home page, when trying to configure the jenkins security seeing above error.

PFA for the initial home page and error page.
[Error page after redirecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3zo9.png)

[Jenkins home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEXR6.png)

Answer (score 0):

This error means that an HTTPS request reaches to a HTTP (plaintext) listener. Check the listeners, some of your services may have an incorrect name (i.e. http) which is not following the naming convention: https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/analysis/ist0118/

I suggest to use $ istioctl pc listeners --address

Answer (score 0):

@Arnau Senserrich,

If it's a http naming issue, in the place it shouldn't even open jenkins login page.
If you see the above image when accessed jenkins through LB, I'm able to enter credentails and able to login. But when I clicked manage jenkins-> Configure Security
I'm seeing above error.

Also tried GW with both http and https:

GW.yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: jenkins-gw
  namespace: jenkins
spec:
  selector:
    custom: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: PASSTHROUGH
    hosts:
    - "*"
```

VS1.yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: jenkins-vs
  namespace: jenkins
spec:
  gateways:
  - jenkins-gw.jenkins
  hosts:
  - '*'
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /jenkinsargo
    route:
    - destination:
        host: argojenkins.jenkins.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 8080
```

VS2.yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: jenkins-vs1
  namespace: jenkins
spec:
  gateways:
  - jenkins-gw.jenkins
  hosts:
  - '*'
  tls:
  - match:
    - port: 443
      sniHosts:
      - "oitat.xyz.com"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: argojenkins.jenkins.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 8080
```

No luck, same issue.